# Puppeteer can't click on li element

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to access a telegram conversation at https://web.telegram.org/k/. I can't click on the li element, I've tried several ways like `page.click()` and `document.querySelector("xxxxxx").click()` but nothing works.

Here's my code:

```
const pup = require('puppeteer')

const url = 'https://web.telegram.org/k/'
async function inicializar() {
  const browser = await pup.launch({
    headless: false
  })
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto(url)
  await page.waitForTimeout(15000)
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector("#auth-pages > div > div.tabs-container.auth-pages__container > div.tabs-tab.page-signQR.active > div > div.input-wrapper > button > div").click()
  })
  await page.waitForTimeout(5000)
  try {
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      document.querySelector("#auth-pages > div > div.tabs-container.auth-pages__container > div.tabs-tab.page-signQR.active > div > div.input-wrapper > button:nth-child(2) > div").click()
    })
  } catch {
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      document.querySelector("#auth-pages > div > div.tabs-container.auth-pages__container > div.tabs-tab.page-sign.active > div > div.input-wrapper > button:nth-child(6) > div").click()
    })
  }
  await page.waitForTimeout(5000)
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector("#auth-pages > div > div.tabs-container.auth-pages__container > div.tabs-tab.page-sign.active > div > div.input-wrapper > div.input-field.input-field-phone > div.input-field-input").childNodes[0].textContent = "+55 11 944407845"
    document.querySelector("#auth-pages > div > div.tabs-container.auth-pages__container > div.tabs-tab.page-sign.active > div > div.input-wrapper > button.btn-primary.btn-color-primary.rp > div").click()
  })
  await page.waitForTimeout(30000)
  const foo = await page.$x('//*[@id="column-left"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/input');
  await foo[0].type("folio_bill_bot")
  await page.waitForTimeout(5000)
  const xp = `/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li/div[1]`;
  const sizeButton = await page.waitForXPath(xp);
  await sizeButton.evaluate(btn => {
    btn.closest("li").dispatchEvent(new Event("mousedown"));
  });
  await page.waitForTimeout(10000);
  //await Promise.all([foo2[0].click()])
  //await foo2[0].click()
  return [page, browser]
}

inicializar()
```

For those who want to look at the HTML:

[image: HTML]

Comment: Are you certain that the elements already are part of the DOM at that point in time? `waitForTimeout()` is rather unreliable in general.

Comment: How do you know you can't click on it? Perhaps the page implemented some automation resistance and did some `e.isTrusted` sort of thing or something like that. Are you sure you're querying the correct element? Try the code in the browser console and see what you get.

Comment: it always returns null or undefined

I always test first in the browser console

Comment: Looks like it's behind a login so there's not much I can do here. But I strongly suggest avoiding `waitForTimeout` as suggested above and instead use `waitForSelector`. Also, [avoid the long browser-generated selectors and paths](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors). There are almost always more precise selectors. Check for shadow roots and iframes.

Comment: None of the `li` elements are clickable there as they are not surrounded by the `<a>` tag.

Comment: I managed to solve using page.mouse.click(x,y)